# How to draw original function, data points and linear regression curve on the same plot with R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, linear-regression, lm

I have created a dummy data with `x` and `y` values. `x` is any value between `0` and `2*pi`. `y` is `sin(x) +- noise`. `noise` is a random value between `0` and `0.5`.

I have created a linear regression curve using this formula: `fit <- lm(ys ~ xs + I(xs^2) + I(xs^3))`.
I am able to draw just the original sine function and the points with the following code:

```
plot(sin, 0, 2*pi,col="green",xlim = c(-0.5, 6.5), ylim = c(-1.5, 1.5))
points(xs, ys,col="blue")
```

I also want to add the fitted curve to the same plot. I did a bit of research and came up with the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(x = xs) + 
  stat_function(fun=sin, geom="line", col="green") +
  geom_point(aes(x = xs, y = ys), col="blue") +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = ys ~ xs + I(xs^2) + I(xs^3), col="red")
```

But it is just plotting the points. How to draw original function, data points and linear regression curve on the same plot with R?

Here is the whole code:

```
xs <- c(0, 2*pi)
ys <- c(runif(1,0,0.5), -runif(1,0,0.5))
for(i in 1:20){
  x <- runif(1, 0, 2*pi)
  y <- sin(x) 
  noise <- runif(1,0,0.5)
  if(i%%2 == 0){
    y <- y + noise
  }
  else{
    y <- y - noise
  }
  xs <- c(xs, x)
  ys <- c(ys, y)
}
data <- data.frame(xs, ys)
fit <- lm(ys ~ xs + I(xs^2) + I(xs^3))

#plot(sin, 0, 2*pi,col="green",xlim = c(-0.5, 6.5), ylim = c(-1.5, 1.5))
#points(xs, ys,col="blue")
#abline(fit)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(x = xs) + 
  stat_function(fun=sin, geom="line", col="green") +
  geom_point(aes(x = xs, y = ys), col="blue") +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = ys ~ xs + I(xs^2) + I(xs^3), col="red")
```

Comment: `ggplot(data, aes(x = xs, y = ys)) + 
  stat_function(fun=sin, geom="line", col="green") +
  geom_point(col="blue") +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, degree = 3), col="red")`

Comment: You must pass a data.frame to ggplot2, you must specify the aesthetic mapping for each stat/geom or in `ggplot`, you must use `x` and `y` (literally) in the formula.

Answer (score 2):

One of the lesser known use cases for the `stat_function()` layer is that you can plug in an anonymous function that predicts based on the linear model you have precalculated.

```r
ggplot(x = xs) + 
  stat_function(fun=sin, geom="line", col="green") +
  geom_point(aes(x = xs, y = ys), col="blue") +
  stat_function(fun = function(x){predict(fit, data.frame(xs = x))}, col = "red")
```

[image]

Your attempt was very close, but the `stat_smooth()` layer needed to know what the aesthetics were, and the formula should be expressed as aesthetics.

```r
ggplot(x = xs) + 
  stat_function(fun=sin, geom="line", col="green") +
  geom_point(aes(x = xs, y = ys), col="blue") +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3), 
              aes(x = xs, y = ys),
              col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: I am not able to see the plot using your first suggestion.

Comment: I'm using ggplot2 3.3.2. I know there have been recent updates to the `stat_function()` function. Maybe this is just a version issue?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different approach.
Modify your data.frame to have two more columns:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>%
  mutate(sin_x = sin(xs), fit = predict(fit))
```

Now create your `ggplot` with three geom layers, one for `ys`, one for `sin_x`, and one for `fit`.

```
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = xs)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = ys)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = sin_x), color = "red", size = 0.5) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = fit), color = "black", size = 1, linetype = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: The curves are not smooth. The plot contains 2 lines(sine and lm) joining all the outputs from the given x values. I need smooth lines for both the functions

Comment: @krnbatta - In that case teunbrand's answer is likely better for your need